# React upload a file to spring controller

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have a Java spring-boot based server and a react JS UI app.
And we need to implement a file upload from the react app to the server.

**Server controller code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aaa/{id}/upload", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Object uploadFile(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {
     ... 
    logic
    ...
}
```

With postman, we can upload the file successfully. We can't do it via the react JS app.

**This is react JS upload file code:**

```
uploadFile(file, type) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        return axios.put(`aaa/1/upload`, file, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=--ABC123Boundary'
            }
        })
            .then(() => {
                NotificationsManager.info('File successfully uploaded.')
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                NotificationsManager.error(err.message, `Error in uploading file`);
            });
    }
```

We tried with boundary, without boundary, with default boundary... nothing works.

**UPDATE: We get this error:**

```
"Bad Request"
exception:
"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException"
message:"Required request part 'file' is not present"
```

What did we do wrong?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: What is the error you received ? check in browser developer tools under network.

Comment: have you checked sending `formData` instead of `file` in your `axios.put` statement and without your `content-type` headers ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be posting `formData` in your request instead of `file`? `axios.put('aaa/1/upload', file`.

Comment: updated with the error